# POST same as PUT for /pubs/:id or is there an implicite route in RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I generate my simple `pubs` _edit form with

```
= form_for @pub do |f|
  - if @pub.errors.any?
  -# fields
```

GETing `/ldc/pubs/1/edit`  (ldc -> namespace)
the form tag gets a POST (?):

```
<form id="edit_ldc_pub_1" class="edit_ldc_pub" method="post" action="/ldc/pubs/1" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

and everything is fine, but there is not route for that:

```
... others
                          DELETE          /ldc/pubowners/:id(.:format)                             ldc/pubowners#destroy
                 ldc_pubs GET             /ldc/pubs(.:format)                                      ldc/pubs#index
                          POST            /ldc/pubs(.:format)                                      ldc/pubs#create
              new_ldc_pub GET             /ldc/pubs/new(.:format)                                  ldc/pubs#new
             edit_ldc_pub GET             /ldc/pubs/:id/edit(.:format)                             ldc/pubs#edit
                  ldc_pub GET             /ldc/pubs/:id(.:format)                                  ldc/pubs#show
                          PUT             /ldc/pubs/:id(.:format)                                  ldc/pubs#update
                          DELETE          /ldc/pubs/:id(.:format)                                  ldc/pubs#destroy
```

shouldn't there be an error?

It is not a problem, because PUT and POST are somehow redundant including the presence of an `:id`

but can I rely on that? And why is there a POST rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last question first:

A "post" is rendered because you really only have GET and POST as options in the form field.

Title question:

What you're missing is that there's a hidden value, e.g.,

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
```

This is rendered by the `form_for` helper. Rails uses the value of `_method` to find the correct route.

The HTTP method from the *browser* is a POST, but Rails uses `_method` if present.